# QDialog not calling MainWindow function

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

The following code should call MainWindow function but it is not calling it. I am using QT IDE.

```
#include "itemdialog.h"
#include "ui_itemdialog.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

ItemDialog::ItemDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ItemDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Status Dialog");

}

ItemDialog::~ItemDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ItemDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *obj=new MainWindow;
    obj->okbuttonclicked(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

the okbuttonclicked() function is implemented in MainWindow.This Dialog is not supposed to open a new Window. Its function is just to return the input taken from user to MainWindow function.

What is problem in this code. Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried fire: obj->show() after obj->okbuttonclicked[...]?

Comment: Why should i call obj->show(), the window is already open. This dialog box is there just to take input from user and then pass it to MainWindow function inorder to take further actions..

Comment: Is your code supposed to create a new main window when a dialog button is pressed...?

Comment: no. The window is already open. This dialog is a child of the MainWindow

Comment: So why are you creating new MainWindow?

Comment: Then why are you creating a new one `MainWindow *obj=new MainWindow;`?

Comment: I have tried it obj.okbuttonclicked() way also. but it also doesn't return input from dialog box to MainWindow.

Comment: Try (in your dialog) get parent, cast it on MainWindow and then fire method.

Comment: Are you calling a main window's function from a dialog? Why? Even if you did it correctly, this is still a bad practice.

Comment: Just wonder, why you thought that "new" will somehow get "old" window?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a horrible attempt at implementing an input dialog. You should emit a signal acknowledging that the user has made an input, and connect that signal to a proper slot in your MainWindow and connect that signal and slot in your MainWindow's constructor. Furthermore, if you are just getting a single string in a modal dialog, you should not reinvent the wheel but use [QInputDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new (invisible) main window, and calling `okbuttonclicked()` on that instead of the one already opened.  You need to pass the existing `QMainWindow` into the dialog box, if it is modal this should be done by using it as the dialogs parent.  Otherwise create a new constructor arg to carry it.

Comment: i have passed Qmainwindow as parent of Qdialog. Now how can i use parent(Qmainwindow) to call its function. can you please tell me with coding

Comment: Koying has shown you in his answer.  But teukkam's answer is a more appropriate fix.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty, but if your QMainWindow is the parent of your QDialog, you could do:

```
void ItemDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *obj=qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(parent());
    if (obj)
        obj->okbuttonclicked(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```